# IE error with jquery counter plugin

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, counter

I've implemented a jquery counter script (count up from say 50 to 100 with different increments) that I found from this question:
[jQuery counter to count up to a target number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number/2540360#2540360)

The scripts works great except for in Internet Explorer 8 (and possibly other IE versions?).

Here's an error message from IE with the URL to the creator of the script's demo.

```
Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 32
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/counter.php
```

I'm just wondering if anyone know how this can be fixed. I'm guessing it has to do with el.html() not finding any data but I can't really figure this out.

Thanks for any help ^^

I would reply to that post if I could but I can't seem to find any way of doing so (I'm new to stackoverflow, I think I lack privileges).

Answer (score 0):

While not an exact answer on how to fix your problem, I would recommend using an actual jQuery plug-in meant for this.

[jCountr](http://www.4g3nt0r.de/blog/jcountr/) - I use this counter on several of my websites for things such as session management and timeouts to auto-save counters on forms. I can vouch for it's ease of use and it works across all browsers. It's completely documented and can be configured to count up, count down, call functions on tick or on finish, you can change the interval it ticks at, etc. I highly recommend checking it out. The ease of setting it up will problem be quicker than working on a painful Internet Explorer bug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've seen that counter, but I don't think it supports how fast the countdown is? Basically the features "time" and "step" for this plugin. How fast say 10 numbers are counted up, and and if it should "skip" numbers just to reach the final destination within x seconds.

Comment: The "interval" option will change how fast the numbers are counted. Say if you wanted 10 numbers counted in 5 seconds, you would change it to 0.5 instead of it's default value of 1. However, I don't know about the skip thing, so perhaps it wouldn't work for you because of that. Sorry!