# Live count - jQuery and .length

Tags: jquery, html, button, counter

I have shopping cart who comes in lightbox, but on this button to call shop cart i have number of added products, I count my div elements (added products) with: *.length*, and that is ok. but how can i count this elements live, if i click on "add to cart" then should automaticly number of products increase.

At the moment my code look like following

```
var elementsInCart =  $('div.cartelements div.cartproducts');

$('#call_cart_button_number').html(elementsInCart);
```

I see always true number of products if i refresh page. I have tried to solve this with click, but that's not true.

I have found some other examples, but there is always something others. [jQuery counter to count up to a target number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number)

Comment: Bind an event listener to their "add to cart" buttons that recounts the number of matched elements.

Comment: Was a good idea, so i'm now on the true way, thanke you