# Jquery animated percentage counter

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, counter

In my vote system I want to show a vote percentage. This percentage is given and calculated in the ajax request (success response). I would like to create something like a live counter up and backwards (if the vote percentage is more or less).

let's say, the vote is now 40 and the success response gives 50 back, I want to show the counter is counting from 40 till 50 (animated).

I tried this by:

```
<b class="countPercentage">40%</b>

$('.countPercentage').animated().text(data.percentage);
```

But no success, it changes only the value from 40 to 50.

Thanks in advance! 
Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery counter to count up to a target number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the counter yourself. Of course the timing can be adjusted, maybe based on the amount of `diff`.

**JavaScript**

```
var display = $('.countPercentage > span');

var currentValue = parseInt(display.text());
var nextValue    = data.percentage;

var diff         = nextValue - currentValue;
var step         = ( 0 < diff ? 1 : -1 ); 

for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        currentValue += step
        display.text(currentValue);
    }, 100 * i)   
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/FR7Aa/)

Comment: i like it "Try before buy" :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of creating your own percentage counter (you can see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/CEbGA/):

```
function timer() {
    if (animator.curPercentage < animator.targetPercentage) {
        animator.curPercentage += 1;    
    } else if (animator.curPercentage > animator.targetPercentage) {
        animator.curPercentage -= 1;    
    }                

    $(animator.outputSelector).text(animator.curPercentage + "%");

    if (animator.curPercentage != animator.targetPercentage) {
        setTimeout(timer, animator.animationSpeed)    
    }
}

function PercentageAnimator() {
    this.animationSpeed = 50;
    this.curPercentage = 0;
    this.targetPercentage = 0;
    this.outputSelector = ".countPercentage";

    this.animate = function(percentage) {
        this.targetPercentage = percentage;
        setTimeout(timer, this.animationSpeed);
    }    
}

var animator = new PercentageAnimator();
animator.curPercentage = 40;
animator.animate(70);
```

Answer (score 0):

Super late but,I used a similar one for my squarespace. Just not percents. I don't know enough about coding to know the variance but hey here's the HTML

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {

var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
$('.counter-value').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },
    {
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
      }
      });
 });
 a = 1;
 }
 });
 </script>
<div id="counter">
 <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-4 counter-value" data-count="58" data-
 desc=>0</div>  
<div class="sqs-col sqs-col-4 counter-value" data-count="42" data-
 desc=>0</div>
<div class="sqs-col sqs-col-4 counter-value" data-count="88" data-
desc=>0</div>
</div>


<style>
  .counter-value { 
font-size: 60px;
line-height:2em;
text-align:center;
padding:17px 0;
 }
.counter-value:after {
content: attr(data-desc);
display:block;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
line-height:1.2em;
```