# How would I go about making a number on my page quickly count up from 0 to 60 on load?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I'm imagining a fast mileage counter style element, similar in style to the spinning numbers on [this](http://www.todaythe12.com/) website (scroll down a little), but with the numbers spinning from zero to 60, or possibly 0, up to 100, resetting back at 0 and then up to 60, and spinning in the same direction.

Here's an image of the static page for reference: http://d.pr/i/F1rc

[image]

It's the percentage in the middle that I want to animate on page load.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You cannot do this using a css animation.

Comment: Agreed - you're going to need some javascript for this...

Comment: Dupe? Someone has written a `Javascript` plugin to count up to a specific number, over a defined time (ms) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2540673/2470724

Comment: Not only that he asks stupid questions. He also didn't even read the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this purely in CSS & HTML, however it is definitely not a sensible choice, using JS would accomplish better, more efficiently.

## [**Example FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ksh/2/)

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.circle {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 999px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 100px 0 0 20px;
  width: 230px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.counter {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  -webkit-animation: counter 4s infinite;
  -moz-animation: counter 4s infinite;
  animation: counter 4s infinite;
  position: relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes counter {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  10% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  20% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  30% {
    top: -150px;
  }
  40% {
    top: -200px;
  }
  50% {
    top: -250px;
  }
  60% {
    top: -300px;
  }
  70% {
    top: -350px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -400px;
  }
  90% {
    top: -450px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes counter {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  10% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  20% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  30% {
    top: -150px;
  }
  40% {
    top: -200px;
  }
  50% {
    top: -250px;
  }
  60% {
    top: -300px;
  }
  70% {
    top: -350px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -400px;
  }
  90% {
    top: -450px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes counter {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  10% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  20% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  30% {
    top: -150px;
  }
  40% {
    top: -200px;
  }
  50% {
    top: -250px;
  }
  60% {
    top: -300px;
  }
  70% {
    top: -350px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -400px;
  }
  90% {
    top: -450px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  +
  <div class='counter'>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
      <li>10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>%
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please make it firefox-compatible? I'm quite curious :)

Comment: Done...should work now :) You'd need to change the speed/numbers etc as necessary.

Comment: This is totally awesome :D

Comment: But I made my answer insane too :P

Answer (score 0):

How about a plugin :

```
$.fn.count = function(speed) {
    return this.each(function(_, elem) {
        var from = parseInt($(elem).data('from') || 0, 10),
            to   = parseInt($(elem).data('to') || 100, 10);

        $(elem).text(from);

        (function run(from, to) {
            $(elem).text(parseInt(from, 10)+1);
            if (from < to-1) setTimeout(function() {run(++from, to)}, speed || 300)
        })(from, to);
    });
}
```

that can easily be used as

```
$(element).count(100);
```

and where you'd set the values as

```
<div data-from="0" data-to="100">0</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hPdz/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may want to use javascripts `setTimeout`.

Let the following be your number container:

```
<div id="number"></div>
```

#### A wild pseudo-class:

```
//Some iterator pseudo-class
function NumberIterator() {
    //The number to start with
    this.number = 0;
    //List of numbers to pass through
    this.goals = [];
    //Private - current goal
    var currentGoal = 0;
    //Whether to infinitelly loop around
    this.infinite = false;
    //Pause between changing number
    this.delay = 50;

    //Timeout ID 
    var t_id = null;
    //Self-reference
    var _this = this;
    //Is running or not
    var running = false;

    //This method will be called automatically
    this.step = function() {
        //If out goal is smaller than number decrease it
        if(this.number>this.goals[currentGoal])
          this.number--;
        //if our goal is larger, increase
        else if(this.number<this.goals[currentGoal])
          this.number++;
        //If equals, perform ongoal actions
        else {
          currentGoal++;
          if(currentGoal>=this.goals.length) {
              if(this.infinite)
                 currentGoal = 0;
              else {
                  this.stop();
              }
              if(typeof this.ongoal == "function")
                 this.ongoal(this.number);
          }
        }



        if(typeof this.onstep == "function")
            this.onstep(this.number);

        if(running) {
            tick();
        }

    }
    this.stop = function() {
        if(t_id!=null) {
            clearTimeout(t_id);
            t_id = null;
        }
        running = false;
    }

    //Start counter with this:
    this.start = function() {
        this.stop();
        running = true;
        this.step();
    }
    //This one is heart of the program. It delays between iterations
    function tick() {
        if(t_id!=null) {
            clearTimeout(t_id);
            t_id = null;
        }
        if(running)
          t_id = setTimeout(function() {_this.step();}, _this.delay);
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
//Save div element reference (it's faster to use reference than function call)
var div = document.getElementById("number");

//Set up ne instance of that class
var iterator = new NumberIterator();
//Configure waypoints
iterator.goals = [100,60,0,60];
//Set it to iterate indefinitely through waypoins (that's quite fun)
iterator.infinite = true;
//On step callback
iterator.onstep = function(num) {
    div.innerHTML = num;
}
//Start the thingy
iterator.start();
```

## [EXAMPLE on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/cKm62/1/)

If the number animation is supposed to be static over-time, I you can also use GIF animation (these can be one-time animations as well). So, if it's going to be allways the same, pick your favorite gif animator and create it as an image. It must get cached on client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
        function count($this){
            var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
            $this.html(++current);
            if(current !== $this.data('count')){
                setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
            }
        }        
      $("span").each(function() {
          $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
          $(this).html('0');
          count($(this));
      });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WpJxn/1/