# Add x every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a number (X) every second starting from todays date to a counter.

**Variables:**
Start date
End date
Number to add every second (X)

**If X is 0.4 the counter would look like this:**

15 september 2014 10:00:01: 0.4
15 september 2014 10:00:02: 0.8
15 september 2014 10:00:03: 1.2

This should go on for for example one year.

I found this question but it starts from zero every time you visit the page: [jQuery counter to count up to a target number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number)

Instead the code I'm looking for has the time as reference.

I've tried to modify the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

        return $(this).each(function() {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

                if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }

                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;

                    if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
        from: 0,  // the number the element should start at
        to: 100,  // the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,  // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,  // the number of decimal places to show
        onUpdate: null,  // callback method for every time the element is updated,
        onComplete: null,  // callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 10000,
            to: 100000,
            speed: 50000000,
            refreshInterval: 50,
            onComplete: function(value) {
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    });
```

My data is:

```
from: 10000, to: 100000, speed: 50000000
```

The from date variable is missing in the code. I don't think this is the most efficient setup. The description at the top is better suited.

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What you get vs. what you expect to get? Please provide more info.

Comment: The current code starts the counter from "zero" every time you refresh the page, what I'm looking for is a function that is liked to the date.

Comment: At a glance, it seems fine to me, let me test it...

Comment: Works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u1eernrg/

Comment: But every time you refresh it starts over.

Comment: Of course it does, you're always defining `from` to be 10000. You have to save the last value if you want it to be able to continue. Tell me what should `from` represent.

Comment: From should for example represent 10 sep 2014

Comment: I don't understand, like the amount of seconds since the 10th Sept?

Comment: If i set 15 sep 2014 as startdate. A number X should be added every second from that date. More clear?

Comment: Maybe count how many seconds from the start date and multiplicate it with X

Comment: How can you add a number to a date?

Comment: No, add it to a separate counter.

Comment: Okay, wrote you an answer, I think it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: It seems to me there is a problem with grasping the default stateless nature of HTTP.  What you are needing to do is add state.  So you want a counter that doesn't start from the beginning right? Is this counter defined on a per user basis (something that could be achieved client side using cookies or HTML5 localStorage) or the same counter for every page visitor (something that would require server-side persistence of the counter value)?

Comment: It should be same for all site visitors. I tried to show what i intended in this JSfiffle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6tzk0oe/2/

Comment: It could show the production pace for a product. Every second from a specific date we produce X products.

Comment: I wrote you code exactly for that in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to the comments, sound like you need a counter from a certain point in time till now.

It's simple to accomplish it using the `Date().getTime()` function which gives you time in milliseconds.

If you need just a seconds counter with a coefficient, you can do something simple like this:

```
var start = new Date('15 september 2014 10:00:00').getTime()/1000 | 0;
var x = 0.4;

var el = document.getElementById('t');

setInterval(function(){
    var output = ((((new Date().getTime()/1000 - start) | 0) * x * 10) | 0) / 10;
    el.innerHTML = '<span>' + new Date() + '</span>' + output;
}, 1000);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bdu4na3t/1/

Comment: But it still starts over when refreshing?

Comment: Yes, because 11th September is always 11th September. What should be the starting number? And the ending number?

Comment: Say it should count from 10 to 1000

Comment: You have too many variables - you can't have both the multiplier and the end result. It's like saying `x * 2 = y` but you want `x = 2` and `y = 3`. Anyway, here's a super simple code I wrote for you, it adds `x` to every second that has passed since the start date.