# How to create a timer "count up" using jQuery Countdown plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, countdown

i am trying to use the [jQuery plugin countdown 2.1](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html) to count the time up. I need to clock to start at 0 and count up one second at a time.

Here is what I have done

```
        $('#MasterBreakTimer').countdown(new Date(), 
        {
                elapsed: true,
                strftime: '%H:%M:%S'
        });
```

but it is not displaying anything

How can I correctly implement a count up clock?

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I need to add an event to display the results like so

```
$('#MasterBreakTimer').countdown(new Date(), 
{
        elapse: true,
        strftime: '%H:%M:%S'
}).on('update.countdown', function(event){
    $(this).html(event.strftime('<span>%H:%M:%S</span>') );
});
```

Comment: Hi, does the countup work with your answer given? I am using http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ as the script, but would like to count ascending not descending. Thank you.