# Digit Counter - Make an animated counter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, css

basically, what I am looking for is an animation for digits, a great example would be on this site: http://www.upper-reach.com/

If you scroll down you'll see their 'Builds completed' etc counting up.

How do I do this?

I would appreciate the answers.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Check the getting started tour to see how to properly ask a question on this site. Flagged for closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number) or you could use the [CountUp.JS](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) plugin.

If you want to count the digits you could do something like this when using CountUp.JS:

```
var myDigit = $(".myDivWithDigits").text();

var options = {
  useEasing : true, 
  useGrouping : true, 
  separator : ',', 
  decimal : '.', 
  prefix : '', 
  suffix : '' 
};
var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement", 0, myDigit, 0, 2.5, options);
demo.start();
```

Comment: in countup it counts the value from zero to the value but i want to count the digits <div><span>5</span><span>6</span></div>

Comment: If you want to count digitis you could do something like: `myDigitsString.length` as the third parameter for the CountUp plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_inner vc_row-fluid" style='text-align:left;'>
         <div class=" full_section_inner clearfix">
<div class="vc_col-sm-4 wpb_column vc_column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="q_counter_holder  center" style=""><span class="counter  random" style="color: #bf1e2e;font-size: 50px;">254,336</span>
                        <span class="separator small" style=""></span>
                        <p class="counter_text" style="font-size: 20px;color: #000000;"></p>
</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```