# Count up to number, then count from there to a different number (at different speed)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to count up a number to a certain point, then once it hits that number, count from there up to a different number using Jquery?

Essentially I want to get to the first number quite quickly, then want to animate to the second number at a much slower pace.

I can't quite get it to switch smoothly to the second number. It just instantly jumps to the very final number. Where am I going wrong?

```js
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
  Counter: $('.Single').text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  },
  complete: function() {
    checker();
  }
});

function checker() {
  base = parseInt($(".Single").text());
  per_day = 24;
  newtarget = (base + per_day);
  $(".Single").replaceWith(newtarget);

  $({ Counter: base }).animate({
    Counter: $('.Single').text()
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() {
      $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    },
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">24</span>
```

Comment: *"I have made a fiddle"*: Did you know you can create an inline fiddle? Use the toolbar...

Comment: @trincot Sorry... done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `replaceWith` use `.text` - replace with gets rid of your element and replaces it with the number, text will put the number inside the element

```js
const $div = $('.Single');
$div.animate({
  Counter: $div.text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function (now) {
      $div.text(Math.ceil(now));
  },
  complete: function() {
    checker();
  }
});


function checker() {
  base = parseInt($div.text());
  per_day = 24;
  newtarget = (base + per_day);
  $div.text(newtarget);                 // change this line

  $({ Counter: base }).animate({
    Counter: $div.text()
  }, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() {
      $div.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    },
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">30000</span>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it but if I put 30000 in the span, it only gets to 29688 before the second counter starts... I thought that's the whole point of the complete parameter? It's not finishing the first count before the second one.

Comment: I think it may be to do with the duration - as it's trying animate a count to 30000 in 1 second, it seems to mess it up (as it means it's asking the browser to do 30000 repaints in a second).  If you give it more time, it seems to be ok (try 5000 duration)

Comment: Hmm this needs a rethink, I need the duration to be 1000 but I need a way to make sure it's actually hit 30000 before moving onto the second counter

Comment: I dont know if this might be of some help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540277/jquery-counter-to-count-up-to-a-target-number

Comment: @Rob I have changed your selector and made the code a bit more effiecient in what it was doing and it seems to run better now and counts to 30000 before carrying on

Answer (score 0):

aww someone beat me to the punch...well encase it helps :

```js
$({
  countNum: 0
}).animate({
  countNum: $('.Single').text()
}, {
  duration: 10000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.countNum));
  },
  complete: function() {
    checker();
  }
});

function checker() {
  base = parseInt($(".Single").text());
  per_day = 24;
  newtarget = (base + per_day);
  $({
    countNum: per_day
  }).animate({
    countNum: newtarget
  }, {
    duration: 30000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function() {
      $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log('complete')
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">24</span>
```

Comment: Thanks anyways. Think I've uncovered a secondary problem though! (see comments on answer)